# Can employee share ownership plan (ESOP) contributions to an RRSP account qualify as HBP repayment?

Tags: taxes, canada, rrsp, repayment, home-buyers-plan

Can employee share ownership plan (ESOP) contributions to an RRSP account be designated as repayment towards a previous withdrawal made under the Home Buyers' Plan?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is Yes, as when you get your RRSP tax form you are able to allocate a portion of that towards repayment of HBP. When contributing towards your RRSP you do not have to identify whether it is repayment of HBP.

Comment: A CRA or other official reference indicating this may increase the value of this answer.